# Create Link List from variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, constexpr

I want to create a link list by taking the variable arguments given at compile time
Description below:

I have a node something like given below:

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    Node(const T& data, Node* next = nullptr ) : m_data(data),
                                                 m_next(next)
    {}
    
    T m_data;
    Node *m_next;
};
```

I have a function which takes variable number of arguments(variadic) like below, and should be able to create a link list from all the arguments and return head*(starting pointer) of the created list

```
template <class ... Ts>
constexpr Node* create(Ts && ... ts) {
    // should be able to create all nodes and return Head* for the given created list
    //return Head
}
```

main function would look like this

```
int main()
{
    auto *k = create(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    auto *n = create();  // should handle no arguments case
    auto *l = create(9,10,11,22,4567,90);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not make this over complicated and just use [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). Use of variadic arguments here will be an overkill.

Also `Node` should be an implementation detail of a list. So create a template class `List` which will be the only thing which uses `Node`.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T m_data;
    Node *m_next;
};

template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List(std::initializer_list<T> ini)
    {
        for (const T& x : ini) {
           push_back(x);
        }
    }

    void push_back(const T& x);
    ....

private:
   std::unique_ptr<Node> m_front;
   Node* m_back;
};
```

This is bad approach, and poor task for interview, but here it is:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    constexpr explicit Node(const T& x) : m_data{x}
    {}

    T m_data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> m_next;
};

template<typename T>
using Node_t = Node<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
template<typename T>
using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<Node_t<T>>;

template<typename T>
constexpr NodePtr<T> create(T&& x)
{
    return std::make_unique<Node_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(x));
}

template <typename T1, typename ... Ts>
constexpr NodePtr<T1>
    create(T1&& x1, Ts && ...xi)
{
    auto r = create(std::forward<T1>(x1));
    r->m_next = create(std::forward<Ts>(xi)...);
    return r;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bbo5Tc

Comment: Actually in the context I am asking, it requires to not change the format, will need to parse the variadic arguments passed onto it via create function.

Comment: If this is a problem form some book or online tutorial / competitive programing, please provide link to it.

Comment: Actually it was asked in an interview, don't have a link since it expired, But the problem statement is same.

Comment: It looks great, Thanks! Though how can we achieve the case for empty parameters in this. Since it requires us to handle that case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full test program. The `create` routine uses standard tail recursion and a bit of variadic templates magic. This uses C++17's `if constexpr`, for C++14 you would have to specialize the `create` to an empty argument list (`return nullptr;`).

Marek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64223262/1182653) also contains valid points about `unique_ptr` and `std::initializer_list`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node_t {
    Node_t(int v = 0, Node_t* n = nullptr): value(v), next(n) {}

    int value;
    Node_t* next;
};

constexpr Node_t* create() {
    return nullptr;
}

template <class Head, class... Tail>
constexpr Node_t* create(Head const& head, Tail const&... tail) {
    Node_t* result = new Node_t(head);
    if constexpr(sizeof...(tail) > 0) {
        result->next = create(tail...);
    }
    return result;
}

void printList(Node_t* n) {
     if (!n)
          return;
     std::cout << n->value;
     if (n->next) {
        std::cout << ", ";
        printList(n->next);
    }
}

int main() {
    Node_t* l = create(1,2,3);
    std::cout<< "List: "; printList(l);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Node_t* l2 = create();
    std::cout<< "EmptyList: "; printList(l2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but if we need to pass the case of empty list, we will still need to specialise create function which should return nullptr. Adding that works. Thanks!

Comment: If you mean that Node_t::value has a templated type, then yes - the create() function has its arguments templated.

Comment: I have added your (correct) suggestion about the empty list handling.

Comment: You can also upvote/accept the answer, if it is good enough for you.

Comment: @Jean-Claude: Copy'n'pasting from local editor. Thanks.